# Yii2 model relationship where not null

Tags: php, yii2

I would like to get all records in a relationship where its not null

so my table are

```
tbl_truck
    id, name

 tbl_checks
   id
   truck_id //foreign key from tbl_truck table id
```

So in my query i have

```
$query = TblTrucksModel::find()
         ->leftJoin('tbl_checks','tbl_trucks.id = tbl_checks.truck_id')
         ->where() //here add the condition
```

So basically i would like to fetch only the id's from `tbl_truck` which are also existent in `tbl_checks`

Nb: `TblTrucksModel` represents the `tbl_trucks` table

How do i go on about this.

Comment: so you want only those `trucks` to show or return in the resultset that have an associated records in the `tbl_checks` otherwise dont?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be using the  operator sintax

```
    $query = TblTrucksModel::find()
     ->leftJoin('tbl_checks','tbl_trucks.id = tbl_checks.truck_id')
     ->where(['not', ['tbl_trucks.id' => null]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

```
$query = TblTrucksModel::find();
$query->select('t.*');
$query->from('tbl_truck t');
$query->leftjoin('tbl_checks c','t.id = c.truck_id');
$query->where('c.id is not null');
$result = $query->all();
```

Comment: have you added this line `$query->from('tbl_truck t');` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you intend not to show the trucks from the `tbl_truck` table that have no associated record in the `tbl_checks` and only show records that have an association then you should use `innerJoin` rather than `leftJoin` as left join will show all the records from the `tbl_truck` showing the `truck_id` as `NULL` for those records that have no association or matching `truck_id` in the `tbl_checks`

```
TblTrucksModel::find()
         ->innerJoin('tbl_checks','tbl_trucks.id = tbl_checks.truck_id')
```

You don't need an extra `where` clause in this case.